# How to update dynamically update text in Java GUI?

Tags: java, swing, oop, user-interface, jlabel

```
private void itemDescription(JPanel jp1, String prodId) {
    JLabel bodyLabel = new JLabel("<html>" + storeManager.getInv().getProd(prodId).getProdName() + "<br/><html>" +
            storeManager.getInv().getProd(prodId).getProdId() + "<br/><html>$" + storeManager.getInv().getProd(prodId).getProdPrice() +
            "<br/><html>" + "Stock Available: " + storeManager.getInv().getStockAmount(prodId) + "</html>");
    jp1.add(bodyLabel);
}
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/okr5U.png)

Hello! So i have a gui and what i am trying to accomplish is that after i click the add to cart button, the stock available in the item description needs to be reduced. I am unsure of how to get it to update dynamically based on the stock that is available in the inventory.

Comment: just save bodylabel somewhere and then use bodylabel.setText("Your new text"); to update the text

Comment: Like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9761544/13187363

Comment: Also please switch to IntelliJ (https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) instead of JavaEditor. IntelliJ is so much better and will help you code

Comment: Don't dynamically add components (like the label). Declare it as an attribute of the class and simply call `setText("the HTML..")` when the content needs to change.

Comment: @Ruskin Janowski you said it twice ;)

Comment: Oops deleted second one